# Why do I need a parameter in a primary constructor without val/var modifier in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

If I create a class, I can pass a parameter:

```
class Person(name: String) {
}
```

I also can write the same, but with val and then I'll be able to use properties to get this value, when I created an object.

```
val person = Person("Name")
person.name
```

The question is: why do I need just a parameter without the val? Where, how and why should I use it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use `var`or `val` in the constructor, you are declaring properties and initializing them directly. If you don't, those parameters are used for initialization purposes:

```
class Customer(name: String) {
    val customerKey = name.toUpperCase()
}
```

Answer (score 6):

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html

It's used when you don't want constructor arguments to become named properties on the class.

If you use `val`, you get a read-only property. If you use `var`, you get a mutable property. Otherwise, you get nothing [auto-defined].