# Difference between "val" parameter, or without "val"?

Tags: kotlin

What is the difference between the resource and applications parameters with and without `val`?

```
class FeedAdapter(context: Context, val resource: Int, val applications: List<FeedEntry>)
```

and

```
class FeedAdapter(context: Context, resource: Int, applications: List<FeedEntry>)
```

Comment: This is covered in https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I need a parameter in a primary constructor without val/var modifier in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610775/why-do-i-need-a-parameter-in-a-primary-constructor-without-val-var-modifier-in-k)

Answer (score 3):

Any `val` parameter will be a class' member; an attribute. Without `val`, that parameter will be just a constructor parameter.

**Kotlin with val**

```
class Foo(val bar: String)
```

**Java equivalent**

```
class Foo {
  String bar;
  public Foo(String bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
  }
}
```

---

**Kotlin without val**

```
class Foo(bar: String)
```

**Java equivalent**

```
class Foo {

  public Foo(String bar) {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use without `val`, you cannot use that variable inside the class, for example,
`class FeedAdapter(context: Context, val resource: Int, val applications: List<FeedEntry>)`
for this, you can access `resource` and `applications` variables in `FeedAdapter` class, but not the `context` variable.